# facebook requests from ios apps are not showing in facebook mobile app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I have an iOS app and a corresponding Facebook app. When I send Facebook requests from the iOS app, they do show under https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests but not in the mobile Facebook app.

The Facebook app is set up as follows:

Basic settings:

- Display name, Namespace, Contact email - filled in
- App domains - blank

iOS settings:

- Bundle ID - filled in
- URL scheme suffix, iPhone Store ID, iPad Store ID - blank (app not submitted to Apple yet)
- Single sign-on, Deep linking - both checked

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I had to fill in at least the iPhone Store ID in iOS settings. Since I didn't have an app ID, I had to simply pick an existing app's ID and enter it there.

I believe this ID is only needed to tell Facebook app where to take the user that doesn't have this app installed, but apparently Facebook is also using it as an indication that the app actually exists. Very insidious of Facebook, if you ask me.